# decompose mixture of lotteries into a sequence of pairs of lotteries

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, logic

I have the following two axioms:

Mixture symmetry(MS): if lotteries $f \sim g$ (in the same equivalence class) then $\alpha f+ (1-\alpha)g \sim \alpha g +(1-\alpha)f$.

Randomization preference(RP)：equiprobable randomization is the best: $f \sim g$ but $f \ne g, $ $\frac{1}{2} f+ \frac{1}{2}g$ $\succ$ $\alpha g +(1-\alpha)f$ for any other $\alpha \in [0,1]，\alpha \ne \frac{1}{2}$. The closer the randomization to the equiprobable one the better.

The two axioms together do not imply the 3-lottery version of MS: 
 If $f \sim g \sim r$, $\alpha f+ \beta g + (1-\beta - \alpha)r \sim \alpha g + \beta f + (1-\alpha-\beta)r$. Because let $g=r$ we would have $\alpha f+ (1-\alpha)g \sim \beta f+ (1-\beta)g$, when $\alpha =\frac{1}{2}$ and $\beta =1$ we would have $\frac{1}{2} f+ \frac{1}{2}g \sim f$ which contradicts with the RP.

Hence, it seems to me the MS combined with RP can only give us the equivalence between 2-lottery mixtures, what if I need to randomize more than 2 lotteries, and compare different mixtures? Can I decompose a n-lottery mixture into a sequence of 2-lottery mixture?

BTW, I use MS to replace the Independence axiom, which states:  if $f \sim g$, then $\alpha f+ (1-\alpha) r \sim \alpha g+ (1-\alpha) r$.
Without this Independence axiom, if we have $a \sim b$, $c \sim d$, I am not sure whether we can have $\alpha a+ (1-\alpha) c \sim \alpha b+ (1-\alpha) d$.

This is a question I run into in my economics research, however, given its probability look, I am not sure it is MathExchange or Econexchange I should post.

Thanks in advance, all suggestions are most welcome!

Comment: Set $f=g$ to see that RP is inconsistent and needs $\ge$ instead.

Comment: @A.S. thanks, corrected.

Comment: But then there is no contradiction extending to 3-lottery version as you are indifferent between mixing equivalent lotteries.

Comment: @A.S. sorry, I should say $f=g$ not applicable as randomization over two identical lotteries are meaningless. We want to see the effect of mixture among different lotteries.

Comment: OK... How do you define equivalence class then?

Comment: @A.S. I start with the class of n degenerate lotteries. Each one of them is a vector $e_i$ in n dimension.  A general lottery can be written as a mixture of these degenerate lotteries. The degree of mixture decides which equivalence class the lottery is in. Two lottery in the same equivalence class should be evaluate as the same according to MS and RP, after been decomposed into sequences of pairs.

Comment: Bob, this is circular definition because MS and RP use $~$ *in the premise*. Are any of the degenerate lotteries in the same class? Given two mixtures, how do I decide if they are int he same equivalence class?

Comment: @A.S. Yes, all the degenerate lotteries are in a class, actually it is the worst class if I put order on all the equivalence classes. To decide whether two mixtures are in the same class is what I want to do with MS and RP, but unlike the Independence axiom, which tells that given a set of lotteries from a equivalent class, any two probability mixtures over them should be in the same class (the initial class), it seems to me the MS can only compare mixtures over two lotteries, this is the reason I what to decompose mixture over n lotteries into a sequence of mixtures over two.

Comment: @A.S. And then additional assumption may still be needed. Sorry for the confusion.